# Mongoose post hook with typescript interface

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, typescript-generics, mongoose-schema

I was following a tutorial using typescript with mongoose. Code looks like following

Interface

```
export default interface IBook extends Document {
  title: string;
  author: string;
  extraInformation: string;

}
```

Schema post save hook

```
BookSchema.post<IBook>('save', function(){
  this.extraInformation = "this is some extra information to put into this entry after the save!"
});
```

Correct me if I am wrong
Here for the hook we use **IBook interface as generic** and inside the has a callback function that is using **"this" what is it pointing to** how can this be used inside a function with no params

BTW perfectly working code

Comment: See [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)